# Get all items using only the Partition key from Dynamodb

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, quarkus

How to get all the items matching only the partition key (table has sort key) using Amazon DynamoDB module.
I'm using the GetItemRequest to query without the sort key.

```
GetItemRequest getItemRequest = getRequest(externalId);
IDMapping.from(dynamoDB.getItem(getItemRequest).item());
```

I get the following error when i query only with partition key with GetItemRequest.

`Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException: The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 6C9BTJCJOTS7I5FI1EBJLIQK3RVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, Extended Request ID: null)`

I'm using the following dependency in my quarkus application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This query is possible using aws cli, aws console and also with the older java aws-sdk.

are there any ways to overcome this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The GetItem request requires the full key (partition and sort). You can do what you want with a [Query request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Java.04.html).

```
    HashMap<String, String> nameMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    nameMap.put("#yr", "year");

    HashMap<String, Object> valueMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    valueMap.put(":yyyy", 1985);

    QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec().withKeyConditionExpression("#yr = :yyyy").withNameMap(nameMap)
        .withValueMap(valueMap);

    items = table.query(querySpec);
```

This example is for a table with a composite key:

- year – The partition key. The attribute type is number.
- title – The sort key. The attribute type is string.